# Initialise slider after jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

I am using a jQuery slider (Swiper) in my project. Initialising the slider works fine if I load the page, but when loading in new content (with slider) from html files the slider does not initialise. The current steps:

Creating a new section:

```
var section = $('<section class="cd-section overflow-hidden '+newSection+'"></section>').appendTo(mainContent);
```

Loading content from html file into new section

`section.load(newSection+'.html .cd-section > *', function(event){...})`;

I'm trying to initialise after this load event, this is not working.

```
section.load(newSection+'.html .cd-section > *', function(event){

    if(typeof Swiper == "undefined") {
        console.log("Ready to rumble");
        $.getScript('js/swiper.jquery.min.js', function() {
            var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                paginationType: 'progress',
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                centeredSlides: true,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                grabCursor: true,
            });
        });
    }
});
```

How can i get the slider to initialise after the load event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the following:

- The index page needs to have the swiper style in the head.
- Call `slidername.update(true)` after the load event, to update the
  slider after DOM manipulation.

See http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api for further reference on the update function.